# Powershell script to download MP4s via HTTP

Tags: powershell

I created a Powershell script to download MP4s and it works fine when I specify a folder. But I'd like to download files from all folders.

This works when I specify the 101GOPRO

```
$iwr = Invoke-WebRequest http://10.5.5.9:8080/videos/DCIM/101GOPRO/
$links = $iwr.Links | select href | where {$_.href -like "*mp4"} | select -expand href
foreach ($link in $links) {
$url = "http://10.5.5.9:8080/videos/DCIM/101GOPRO/" + $link
$target = "C:\"
start-bitstransfer -source $url -destination $target -TransferType Download
}
```

How do I get all the .mp4s in all folder by only specifying http://10.5.5.9:8080/videos/DCIM/

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without more information, this is only a guess, but you could modify this for your situation

## ! code not tested - use at your own risk

```
$site = 'http://10.5.5.9:8080/videos/DCIM/'
$base = iwr $site
$subs = $base.links.href

$subs

# only remove this when you have filtered your results
return

foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    $subsite = join-path $site $sub

    write-host $subsite

    $iwr = iwr $subsite
    $links = $iwr.Links.href | where {$_ -like "*mp4"}
    foreach ($link in $links) {
        $url = join-path $subsite $link
        
        write-host $url

        start-bitstransfer -source $url -destination 'c:\' -TransferType Download
        
        # this is an alternative to start-bitstransfer
        #iwr $url -outfile "c:\$(split-path $url -leaf)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with a slight modification but you were spot on.

I changed $subsite = join-path $site $sub to $subsite = $site + $sub, didn't like join-path for some reason.

Thanks!